# The virt-manager displays "Gtk couldn't be initialized"

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, gtk, x11-forwarding

I am running the `virt-manager` on `RHEL 7.0`, but it always display "`Gtk couldn't be initialized`":

```
[root@dhb5 ~]# virt-manager --debug --nofork
2015-08-17 03:21:09,895 (cliutils:75): virt-manager startup
2015-08-17 03:21:09,895 (virt-manager:201): Launched as: ['/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager', '--debug', '--nofork']
2015-08-17 03:21:09,896 (virt-manager:202): virt-manager version: 0.10.0
2015-08-17 03:21:09,896 (virt-manager:203): virtManager import: <module 'virtManager' from '/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/__init__.pyc'>

** (virt-manager:10141): WARNING **: Could not open X display
2015-08-17 03:21:09,957 (virt-manager:246): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 233, in main
    Gtk.Window()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 416, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Gtk couldn't be initialized")
RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized

Gtk couldn't be initialized
```

And the `X11` related configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is like this:

```
[root@dhb5 ~]# grep -i x11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

I try to google many posts, and can't find the answer for my question. Could anyone can give some clues on this issue?

Comment: **virt-manager:10141: WARNING : Could not open X display**:  you do not have an X display on which to open virt-manager.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ssh -vv -X x.x.x.x
```

If it appears:

> debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.

then, try with:

```
yum install xauth
```

(install it on virtual host).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sitting there scratching your head like us for days on this... this is what worked for us.

Edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and try setting "**AddressFamily**" to "**inet**" if you are using a strictly ipv4 network.

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Remember to restart sshd.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this helped:

- Delete the **.Xauthority** file in your home folder (on the KVM server)
- **logout** and **login** again; the file magically recreated
- and most importantly: virt-manager started working again